# Java - Multiple Package In Eclipse Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, package, instanceof

I have the following set of packages within my source folder.
The packages are shapes,model,views.

Say I have a class file in my model folder that has the following piece of code:

```
  shapes.interfaceforshapes[][] temp = model.get2dshapearray();


if(temp[x][y].getClass().isInstance(shapes.cTriangle)){

            }
```

Please note in the above code `temp[x][y]` will return a class that interfaces my `shapeInterface`
and all classes within the shapes folder interface this.

Am I doing the correct thing to say "Is the class within my array of type cTriangle"?

I currently get the error:

> shapes.cTriangle cannot be resolved to a variable

but I don't want to match a variable, I want to test it agaisnt the class `cTriangle` within my package shape.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `instanceOf` operator if you want to check if the object is an instance of a certain class, while the `isInstance` method expects an instance of a class.

```
  if( temp[x][y] instanceOf shapes.cTriangle) {//dosomething }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not how `isInstance(Object)` works. You have to call it on a class and pass in the object you want to match. You would do:

```
shapes.cTriangle.class.isInstance(temp[x][y]);
```

assuming `cTriangle` is a class and `temp[x][y]` returns an object and you want to check if that object is of type `cTriangle`.

Comment: I like this hence the upvote but the simpleness of the mark correct one is easier and more understand able